# How do I make the HipChat emoticon bigger?

Tags: emoji, hipchat

When I'm adding an emoticon on HipChat I can see the following dashboard:

[image]

I don't my emoticon to be the smallest possible one `@1x`. Instead, I'd like it to be `@4x`.

- How do I make a larger emoticon?

Answer (score 2):

Various size emoticons are used for display on various screen pixel densities, rather than actually showing the emoticon at different sizes. They cannot be accessed via a shortcut during chat, i.e. there is no (zoidberg@4x) or anything similar. I wish there was.